# After compiling ans installing wxPython Robot IDE cannot see it

Tags: python, compilation, makefile, wxpython, installation

I have just compiled wxPython `2.8.12.1` downloaded from sourceforge, with the following log of make install (this is just the install part). I have ran `make` in the main dir and then `make install` (with this output).

```
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_base-2.8.so /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_base-2.8.so.0.8.0 /usr/local/lib
(cd /usr/local/lib ; rm -f libwx_base-2.8.so libwx_base-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_base-2.8.so.0.8.0 libwx_base-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_base-2.8.so.0 libwx_base-2.8.so)
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_base_net-2.8.so /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_base_net-2.8.so.0.8.0 /usr/local/lib
(cd /usr/local/lib ; rm -f libwx_base_net-2.8.so libwx_base_net-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_base_net-2.8.so.0.8.0 libwx_base_net-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_base_net-2.8.so.0 libwx_base_net-2.8.so)
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.so /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.so.0.8.0 /usr/local/lib
(cd /usr/local/lib ; rm -f libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.so libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.so.0.8.0 libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.so.0 libwx_gtk2_core-2.8.so)
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.so /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.so.0.8.0 /usr/local/lib
(cd /usr/local/lib ; rm -f libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.so libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.so.0.8.0 libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.so.0 libwx_gtk2_adv-2.8.so)
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.so /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.so.0.8.0 /usr/local/lib
(cd /usr/local/lib ; rm -f libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.so libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.so.0.8.0 libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.so.0 libwx_gtk2_html-2.8.so)
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.so /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.so.0.8.0 /usr/local/lib
(cd /usr/local/lib ; rm -f libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.so libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.so.0.8.0 libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.so.0 libwx_gtk2_qa-2.8.so)
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_base_xml-2.8.so /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_base_xml-2.8.so.0.8.0 /usr/local/lib
(cd /usr/local/lib ; rm -f libwx_base_xml-2.8.so libwx_base_xml-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_base_xml-2.8.so.0.8.0 libwx_base_xml-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_base_xml-2.8.so.0 libwx_base_xml-2.8.so)
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.so /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.so.0.8.0 /usr/local/lib
(cd /usr/local/lib ; rm -f libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.so libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.so.0.8.0 libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.so.0 libwx_gtk2_xrc-2.8.so)
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.so /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.so.0.8.0 /usr/local/lib
(cd /usr/local/lib ; rm -f libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.so libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.so.0.8.0 libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.so.0 libwx_gtk2_aui-2.8.so)
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.so /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c /root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/lib/libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.so.0.8.0 /usr/local/lib
(cd /usr/local/lib ; rm -f libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.so libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.so.0.8.0 libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.so.0; ln -s libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.so.0 libwx_gtk2_richtext-2.8.so)
(if test -d utils/wxrc ; then cd utils/wxrc && make all ; fi) 
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/utils/wxrc'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/utils/wxrc'
(if test -d utils/wxrc ; then cd utils/wxrc && make install ; fi) 
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/utils/wxrc'
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -c wxrc /usr/local/bin
rm -f /usr/local/bin/wxrc /usr/local/bin/wxrc-2.8
/usr/bin/install -c wxrc /usr/local/bin
mv -f /usr/local/bin/wxrc /usr/local/bin/wxrc-2.8
(cd /usr/local/bin && ln -s wxrc-2.8 wxrc)
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/packages/wxPython/wxPython-src-2.8.12.1/utils/wxrc'
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/bin
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/lib/wx/config
/usr/bin/install -c lib/wx/config/gtk2-ansi-release-2.8 /usr/local/lib/wx/config
(cd /usr/local/bin && rm -f wx-config && ln -s /usr/local/lib/wx/config/gtk2-ansi-release-2.8 wx-config)
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/share/locale
for l in ca cs da de el es fi fr hu id it ja nl pl ru sl sv tr uk zh zh_CN zh_TW ; do \
  /usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/share/locale/$l ; \ 
  /usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/share/locale/$l/LC_MESSAGES ; \ 
  if test -f ./locale/$l.mo ; then \
  /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./locale/$l.mo /usr/local/share/locale/$l/LC_MESSAGES/wxstd.mo ; \ 
  fi ; \ 
  done
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/share/locale
for l in it ; do \
  /usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/share/locale/$l ; \ 
  /usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/share/locale/$l/LC_MESSAGES ; \ 
  if test -f ./locale/msw/$l.mo ; then \
  /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./locale/msw/$l.mo /usr/local/share/locale/$l/LC_MESSAGES/wxmsw.mo ; \ 
  fi ; \ 
  done
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/share/aclocal
(cd . ; /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  wxwin.m4 /usr/local/share/aclocal)
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/share/bakefile/presets
(cd ./build/bakefiles/wxpresets/presets ; /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  wx.bkl wx_unix.bkl wx_win32.bkl /usr/local/share/bakefile/presets)
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-ansi-release-2.8/wx
for f in setup.h ; do \
  if test ! -d /usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-ansi-release-2.8/wx/`dirname $f` ; then \
  /usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-ansi-release-2.8/wx/`dirname $f`; \
  fi; \
  /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 ./lib/wx/include/gtk2-ansi-release-2.8/wx/$f /usr/local/lib/wx/include/gtk2-ansi-release-2.8/wx/$f; \
  done
/usr/bin/install -c -d /usr/local/include/wx-2.8
```

After that I have downloaded robotframework-ide from here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/robotframework-ride

and ran :

```
python setup.py install
```

with the following output: http://pastebin.com/TqiBcs78

```
...
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robotide/action/actioninfo.py to actioninfo.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robotide/action/shortcut.py to shortcut.pyc
running install_egg_info
running egg_info
writing requirements to src/robotframework_ride.egg-info/requires.txt
writing src/robotframework_ride.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to src/robotframework_ride.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to src/robotframework_ride.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'src/robotframework_ride.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'src/robotframework_ride.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
removing '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robotframework_ride-1.3-py2.7.egg-info' (and everything under it)
Copying src/robotframework_ride.egg-info to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robotframework_ride-1.3-py2.7.egg-info
running install_scripts
copying build/scripts-2.7/ride_postinstall.py -> /usr/local/bin
copying build/scripts-2.7/ride.py -> /usr/local/bin
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/ride_postinstall.py to 755
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/ride.py to 755
No wxPython installation detected!

Please ensure that you have wxPython installed before running RIDE.
You can obtain wxPython 2.8.12.1 from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/
```

why can't it see my wxPython ? I am using Red Hat 6

Comment: If you run Python 2.7, can you import wx?

Comment: @MikeDriscoll "ImportError: No module named wx"

Comment: Then it didn't install correctly or you have multiple versions of Python installed and it installed against something other than 2.7.

Comment: @MikeDriscoll That was the problem - I have installed it for python 2.6 and wanted to run RIDE with 2.7 (I don't know how that happened) but the issue is resolved. You can post an answer with explanation that it has might have been installed for different python version.

Comment: Alright. I went ahead and submitted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely to be one of two problems:

- The package didn't install correctly and needs to be reinstalled
- You have multiple Python versions installed and the package installed against one of the others.

If it's the latter, you can usually fix it by reinstalling using the appropriate Python:

```
/path/to/python27 setup.py install
```